# How Do I Insert system time Into Ms Access Using Java?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I have just created a simple Student Registration Form using Java(Netbeans). It has several columns to enter the students' data such as regNo, name, address, etc and a Insert button which inserts the data into the table created in MS Access.It works fine.But I need to store the time when a user fills that form.It means when a user fills that form, the system time should be captured and stored in the table for each entry(each tuple). So I want to know how to get the system time and insert into MS Access database.I found the following code.But I don't know how to pass the time captured by the code to the database.I have already created the field for enter the time in the database.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date currentTime = cal.getTime();
```

This is the code I wrote to pass time to the table.....

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into RegInfo(RegNo,StudName,Address,"
               + "Telephone,Stream,RegDate,Time) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setLong(6,currentTime.getTime());
```

I used your code Razvan. It is working really good but it doesn't insert the Time into the table......("System.out.println" is working properly).....

```
 final String t1 = "hh:mm:ss";
 final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(t1);
 final String formattedTime = df.format(new java.util.Date());
 ps.setString(7, formattedTime);
 System.out.println("formattedTime "+formattedTime);
```

Comment: Either use a java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: Why have you tagged as MySQL, but mention using MS Access?

Comment: SQL is a computer language for working with sets of facts and the relationships between them. Relational database programs, such as Microsoft Office Access, use SQL to work with data.

Comment: MySQL is a type of Database, like MS Access, MS SQL, PostgreSQL, H2, DB2 ... hence the question

Comment: I used ODBC. Is there any other way to connect to MS Access database rather using MySql commands.

Comment: You're misunderstanding, mysql is a database, sql, as you've stated, is standard query language, they are different. There is a JDBC driver available for direct access, but you'd still need to use sql

Comment: can't MS Access database be accessed by sql commands with ODBC???

Comment: Yes, ODBC is just a common level driver that facilitates the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `Now()` function in your INSERT query:

```java
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr)) {
    String sql;
    sql = "INSERT INTO RegInfo (RegNo, StudName, Address, Telephone, Stream, RegDateTime) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, Now())";
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setInt(1, 3);
        ps.setString(2, "Gord");
        ps.setString(3, "123 Main St");
        ps.setString(4, "416-555-1212");
        ps.setString(5, "Standard");
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

That will work for both JDBC-ODBC (obsolete, removed from Java 8) and [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)).

Note that Date/Time columns in Access always have both a Date and Time component, so you don't need to maintain separate columns for `RegDate` and `Time`.

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear.It really works.It really helped me.Thanks a lot Thompson.....................

Answer (score 0):

The generic form could be :

```
    final String DB_DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/YYYY"; //not sure about this, modify to fit your Access date format
    final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DB_DATE_FORMAT);
    final String formattedDate = formatter.format(new Date());
```

Comment: Why not just use java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp?

Comment: I used your code Razvan. It is working really good but it doesn't insert the Time into the table......("System.out.println" is working properly).....code is given at the top of the page.......

Answer (score 0):

your time is not the first column in the insert statement it is number 6 so just change your ps parameter as 
ps.setLong(6,currentTime.getTime());